# Brew older version of mysql not available at cmd line

Tags: macos, homebrew

I've installed mysql 5.7 via brew. The binary files are installed at `/usr/local/opt/mysql\@5.7/bin/` however I can't access these files as this location isn't in my path.

Is there a brew way to fix this rather than me making symlinks around the system myself?

Comment: This may help: https://gist.github.com/nrollr/3f57fc15ded7dddddcc4e82fe137b58e ?

Answer (score 3):

The Homebrew way of "fixing" this is to use `link --force`:

```
brew link --force mysql@5.7
```

Alternatively, you can add this location to your `$PATH` by modifying it in your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile`:

```
export PATH="$(brew --prefix mysql@5.7):$PATH"
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple "brew way" to do this is answered [here](https://discourse.brew.sh/t/how-to-revert-from-mysql-8-0-11-to-a-specific-older-version-such-as-5-7-21/2431/3)

```
$ brew info mysql (to get info about the installed versions)
$ brew switch mysql 5.7.21 (to switch to a stable version)
```